# Nginx proxy_pass to another server hosting WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I recently decided to give Nginx a try on one droplet, but I still need to proxy_pass the path http://tld.com/guides to another Apache droplet hosting wordpress

Here is my proxypass conf:

```
location /guides {
  rewrite ^/guides/(.*)$ /$1 break;

  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass http://droplet_private_ip:80;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

The this is that Nginx is redirecting all wordpress's php files to the fpm, I think it's due to this

```
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
```

Is there a way to exclude all requests coming from /guides from being executed by local fpm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it. Just in case someone has the same problem. This fixed my problem

```
    location ~* ^((?!\/guides)(.+)\.php)$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

            # With php5-cgi alone:
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

This part exactly

```
location ~* ^((?!\/guides)(.+)\.php)$ {
```

It makes sure that all .php files from /guides are not handeled by the fpm